# How to block specific subdomain or path on computer?

Tags: windows, web-filtering

I have my kids computer that I've set up for his zoom etc.
I have Kaspersky Safe Kids but this doesn't allow special configuration by subdomain.
I want to allow `amazon.com` but disallow `amazon.com/gp/video`

I'm looking for an option that can be separately password protected outside of windows administrator. So not:

- Edit to Hosts file
- Firewall rule

Thanks.

Comment: amazon.com/gp/video is not a sub-domain. A sub-domain can be gp.video.amazon.com.

Comment: @Overmind sorry, whats the proper loose term for a path variable?

Comment: It is a sub-page of a website.

Answer (score 0):

You need a http(s) proxy. Which one is the best for you on Windows, depends on the details, but that is what you need.

Practically all proxy can be configured to filter urls (by patterns, hostnames, etc).